# Suitescript 2:0: Create search - explained in SQL

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have two datasets, "s" and "s2".

I want to find all combinations of "item" and "internalID" in "s" that is not in "s2". And my final result would be an array of item and formulanumeric from "s".

In SQL, I would have done something like:

SELECT s.item, s.internalID, s.formulanumeric

FROM s

LEFT JOIN s2 ON s.item = s2.item AND s1.internalID = s2.internalID

WHERE s2.item IS NULL and s2.internalID is NULL

or

SELECT s.item, s.formulanumeric

FROM s

WHERE CONCAT(s.Item, s.internalID) not in (SELECT CONCAT(s2.item, s2.InternalID)

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

```
    var s = search.create({
        type : search.Type.TRANSACTION,
           columns:
           [
              search.createColumn({name: "item"}),
              search.createColumn({name: "formulanumeric", formula: "({quantity}-NVL({quantitycommitted},0))-nvl({quantityshiprecv},0)"}),
              search.createColumn({name: "internalid", label: "InternalID"})
           ],
        filters:
        [
            ["type","anyof","SalesOrd"], 
            "AND", 
            ["mainline","is","F"], 
            "AND", 
            ["internalidnumber","equalto",so], 
            "AND", 
            ["taxline","is","F"], 
            "AND", 
            ["shipping","is","F"], 
            "AND", 
            ["item.type","anyof","Assembly"], 
            "AND", 
            ["custcol_custcol","is","T"],
            "AND", 
            ["formulanumeric: ({quantity}-NVL({quantitycommitted},0))-nvl({quantityshiprecv},0)","greaterthan","0"]
        ]
    });
    

   var s2 = search.create({
   type: search.Type.TRANSACTION,
       columns:
       [
          search.createColumn({name: "item", summary: "GROUP", label: "item"
          }),
          search.createColumn({name: "internalid",join: "custbody_customfield", summary: "MAX", label: "InternalID"
          })
       ],
       filters:
       [
          ["mainline","is","T"], 
          "AND", 
          ["type","anyof","WorkOrd"], 
          "AND", 
          ["custbody_internalID","noneof","@NONE@"]
       ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to run this two search first and then  make comparision

```
              var result_s=  s.runPaged({
                pageSize: 1000
              });

var tableS=[];

  var k = 0;
              result_s.pageRanges.forEach(function(pageRange) {
                var page= result_s.fetch({ index: pageRange.index });
                page.data.forEach(function(r) {
                    k++
                tableS.push({
                        "item": r.getValue({name:"Item"}),
                        "formulanumeric":r.getValue({name:"formulanumeric"}),
                        "internalid": r.getValue({name:"internalid"}),
                                              

                });
            });
```

Do the same with S2  and now you have two array and now compare  with every() o foreach like in javascript